# Saxon 9.6 Processor constructor throwing error

Tags: c#, xml, xslt-2.0, saxon, processor

I am trying to transform one XML file into multiple XML files using XSLT 2.0 using VS 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 with Saxon 9.6 stable version. I am calling XSL transformation using C# code, where I am creating Processor class instance using below line:

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
```

But when I run code, it throws the below error:

[image]

Does anybody know what is missing or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen this one before and I don't recognize what's wrong.

Comment: Looks like you are writing to an SQL Server Database and the parameter aren't matching between c# and server.  Looks like it is a culture issue where your are transferring a date in US format and database expects England format (or similar type issue like number using decimal points instead of commas).  In these cases you should always define your SQL using parameters and add parameters to the sql command.

Comment: Hi jdwend, no I am not using any parameter to pass in script, and If I remove this XML to XML script component using XSLT, it run like butter.

Comment: Hi Michael Key, if you don't recognize error, how anybody else can help me as as Saxon is your baby,  please point any possible reason or anything which i SHOULD CHECK to see everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update if anybody in same boat, I uninstall Saxon 9.6 and install newer version 9.7 and it worked, strange but true.

Comment: That suggests it was some kind of installation or configuration error, perhaps a corruption in your registry or something like that.